# Looking for shorter way to handle cache properties in a JS class

Tags: javascript

I have class with a good dozen or so methods which return one value per method. Each method's return value only needs to be calculated once, even if the method is called many times. So, I am using this approach to avoid doing the same work over and over:

```
class myClass {
    myFunc = () => {
        if (typeof this._myCacheVar === "undefined") {
            this._myCacheVar = /* do stuff to get the value */;
        }
        return this._myCacheVar;
    }
}
```

However, over dozens of methods, this approach gets really long-winded and repetitious. I know that classes can have getters and setters for properties, but that's even **more** long-winded.

Is there a good way to shorten this code?

**PS:** Some of these values can be falsy, hence the `typeof` check instead of just checking `if (this._myCacheVar)`.

Comment: Is there a better way.... probably not.

Comment: Your methods don't take arguments? If they do, they should play a role in the cache lookup...

Comment: No arguments, no.

Answer (score 4):

If you are worried about *repeating* the code for every method of your class, just make one function that does the job.

You could apply such a decorator on each method of your class by iterating its methods (which are on the prototype).

Secondly, you can shorten the cache supporting code by making the cached entry a plain object that has a value property that contains the return value. With such object wrapper the test-and-set code can make use of the `??=` operator:

```js
function enableCache(func) {
    const cache = {};
    return function(...args) {
        return (cache[JSON.stringify([this, ...args])] ??= {
            value: func.apply(this, args)
        }).value;
    };
}

function enableCacheOnMethods(cls) {
    const obj = cls.prototype;
    for (const method of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)) {
        if (typeof obj[method] === "function" && method !== "constructor") { // method of cls
            obj[method] = enableCache(obj[method]);
        }
    }
}

// Demo
class myClass {
    divisors(n) { // Example method (without caching)
        console.log(`executing divisors(${n})`);
        const arr = [];
        for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) arr.push(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    factorial(n) { // Example method (without caching)
        console.log(`executing factorial(${n})`);
        let res = 1;
        while (n > 1) res *= n--;
        return res;
    }
}

enableCacheOnMethods(myClass);

let obj = new myClass;
console.log(...obj.divisors(15));
console.log(...obj.divisors(48));
console.log(obj.factorial(10));
console.log(...obj.divisors(15)); // Uses the cache
console.log(obj.factorial(10)); // Uses the cache
```

Comment: It won't work with OP's code directly because `myFunc = () => {` is not a method but a property and can't be accessed without an instance. Nevertheless, this is a much better solution than mine

Comment: Yep, that's why I mentioned "(which are on the prototype)"... otherwise you have to repeat the decoration on each instance. Another concern is that the instance should not have state that influences the results of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a proxy instead of changing every method

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860903/5089567

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop) {
        const origMethod = target[prop];
        if (typeof origMethod == 'function') {
          const key = '_' + prop
          return function(...args) {
            if (key in target) {
              return target[key]
            }
            target[key] = origMethod.apply(target, args)
            return target[key]
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }

  myFunc = () => {
    return Math.random()
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass

console.log(instance.myFunc())
console.log(instance.myFunc())
```

Comment: No need for a complicated proxy. The methods are known in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One way to shorten it is to use decorators but it is an experimental feature for now. The JS decorator proposal is in stage 3 right now [TC9/proposal-decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators). I was not able to run it with NodeJS or set it up to get it working, didn't find enough materials on the internet, however I used [babeljs/repl](https://babeljs.io/repl) with stage-3 preset to get browser-compatible JS code and tested it.

**A decorator function has the form (more on the proposal page):**

```js
type ClassMethodDecorator = (value: Function, context: {
  kind: "method";
  name: string | symbol;
  access: { get(): unknown };
  static: boolean;
  private: boolean;
  addInitializer(initializer: () => void): void;
}) => Function | void;
```

**Example of a class with cache:**

```js
function cache(value, { kind, name, addInitializer }) {
    // If nothing is returned, nothing is modified
    if (kind !== "method") return;
    
    // This is used to bind the function to the class instance
    // Read more about the initializer on the proposal page
    addInitializer(function () {
        // Initializing the cache on the class instance
        if (this.cache === undefined) this.cache = {};
        if (this.cache[name] === undefined) this.cache = {};
        // Binding the function to class instance
        this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
    })

    // "this" is a global object if you do not use addInitializer
    // because the "this" in the returned function is the "this"
    // of the cache function which is global object
    return function(...args) {
      const argsKey = args.join("-");
      if (this.cache[argsKey] === undefined) {
            console.log("Caching the output");
            this.cache[argsKey] = value(...args);
      }
      return this.cache[argsKey];
    }  
}

class exampleClass {
    @cache add(x,y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}

const c = new exampleClass();
console.log("First call", c.add(5, 5));
// -> "Caching the output"
// -> "First call 10"

console.log("Second call", c.add(5, 5));
// -> "Second call 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @trincot, I came up with this, which seems to work okay.

Open to suggestions on ways to improve it. (Also, TS doesn't like `this[method]` very much.)

```
class myClass {
    constructor() {
        for (const method of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)) {
            if (typeof this[method] === 'function' && method.indexOf('_get') === 0) {
                const theValue = this[method]();
                Object.defineProperty (
                    this,
                    method,
                    { value: () => theValue, writable: false}
                )
            }
        }
    }

    _getSomeValue = () => {
        return /* do work here*/;
    }

    _getSomeValue2 = () => {
        return /* do work here*/;
    }

    _getSomeValue3 = () => {
        return /* do work here*/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the work to be done when the respective method is called for the first time, or do you want it to be done upfront in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @trincot, seems to work slightly faster

```
const myFunc = {
    div(n){
    console.log(`executing divisors(${n})`);
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  },
  fact(n){
    console.log(`executing factorial(${n})`);
        let res = 1;
        while (n > 1) res *= n--;
        return res;
  }
}

console.log(...myFunc.div(15));
console.log(...myFunc.div(48));
console.log(myFunc.fact(10));
console.log(...myFunc.div(15));
console.log(myFunc.fact(10));
```

**Update:**
[test](https://perf.link/#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%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%3D)

Comment: I don't see how this does any caching. Why do you think it's faster?